# How to open the executable file in this Java Project? I tried opening all the .jar files already

Tags: java, jar, applet, executable-jar

How to open the executable file in this Java Project? I would like to play this game. I tried opening all the .jar files already, but I get "Failed to load Main-Class manifest attributes from" the file

https://github.com/lisaglendenning/softquor

The executable is at /dist/softquor.jar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have said already, this jar is not a standalone App. It's actually an client server application.

I took a quick look, you can exercise the client like this:

Assuming `softquor.jar` is in your current working directory.

In one console, start the server

```
java -cp softquor.jar softquor.Server 8080
```

In another console start the Text client (you can start multiple clients!)

```
java -cp  softquor.jar softquor.TextClient localhost 8080
```

From the class name I do say the TextClient will let you enter some command and play the game.
If you get something like `ClassNotFoundException` then it means the project is using some third party jar file. Unfortunately you will have to find out those dependencies yourself since there is no clear documentation on that.

Comment: I entered `java -cp softquor.jar softquor.Server 8080` in DOS, I got an error that says `Error: Could not find or load main class softquor.Server`

Comment: did you put softquor.jar in your current working directory? If you change dir to c:\softquor, then softquor.jar should be at c:\softquor\softquor.jar

Answer (score 1):

I would assume the file in /dist/softquor.jar is the executable file.

You can explore contents of a JAR file just like any other zip files using a winzip. Inside you will find a /META-INF/ folder which will have the entry class.

From command prompt you can run it just like any other .jar file. Just make sure you use the full package name.

Comment: You are correct, I tried running the executable by double clicking on it, but I always get the same error :(

Comment: I noticed that there's no main inside the softquor\META-INF\MANIFEST.MF file. You can right click it and choose "Extract to.." and you can check it's contents. 

Oh and btw since the source code is given you might want to check the files. As far as I can see. I see a Server.class, a Client.class, a ClientListener.class and a ClientTest.class. You can run the server and test it using TestClient.class

Comment: im hoping I would be able to play the game within the file, what do I need to do to play the game?

Answer (score 1):

The softquor.jar isn't executable. There is no Main-Class defined in the jar manifest. I looked around briefly and did not see an obvious `main` entry point that wasn't in a test class. Though there was an a class that extended JApplet so you could possibly run the jar from a webpage using the java plugin.

Tough to tell as there appears to be no documentation for this project other than a short README file.

Comment: can you please show me how to open the file? Thank you Thank you Thank you!

Comment: A jar file is just a zip archive with a fancy extension. You can extract it with a file archiving tool of your choice. Or you can use `jar -xvf <jar-file>`

Comment: I can extract the files within softquor.jar, but non of them is executable that allows me to play the game